# Issue with Intel i350 NIC

Tags: linux, dell, nic

We are frequently facing an issue where one of the network interface(Intel Ethernet Controller i350) goes down often with the kernel log having some call trace and an error saying:

```
 [202323.307358] Hardware name: PowerEdge C8220
 [202323.307359] NETDEV WATCHDOG: eth0 (igb): transmit queue 3 timed out
 [202323.307466] igb 0000:02:00.0: eth0: Reset adapter
```

We ran some basic online and offline tests using ethtool and many got failed.

[image]

To debug the issue further we took the `EEPROM and register dump using ethtool` and found that it was completely with binary 1 resulting in `FFFFFF.....`

Has anyone faced such kind of issue before ?

Can someone please help me in debugging the issue further.

**Edit: **

I updated the device driver from 3.0.6 to 5.0.6. but `ethtool` is showing wrong information

```
# ethtool -i eth1
driver: igb
version: 3.0.6-k2
firmware-version: 1.5-7

# modinfo igb
filename:       /lib/modules/2.6.32-5-amd64/kernel/drivers/net/igb/igb.ko
version:        5.0.6
```

I dont know how is it showing like this.

Can we update the firmware over SSH session ?

Comment: Is the firmware and driver upgraded?

Comment: @pauska: I found that drivers are not up to date. Let me update it. But this issue comes only when we put the machine into production. Can i reproduce it and verify that driver upgrade helped before adding it to production.

Comment: Was that a question?

Comment: There are several firmware upgrades here: http://www.dell.com/support/drivers/us/en/04/Product/poweredge-c8000

Comment: @pauska: thank you for the link .. Just updated the driver. I want to know that can i update the firware remotely over ssh session ?

Comment: @pauska: Actually we have around 50 C8220 prod boxes and all are running in old firmware and driver. Just worried that this issue wont hit every machine.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11835/discussion-between-pradeepchhetri-and-pauska)

Comment: @pauska: I updated the question. Can you help me with it.

Comment: @pradeepchhetri . Did you find a solution to this issue?